# Xpath slow running query

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm querying an xml using Xpath and JavaScript. The query get the results but damm slow and it takes ages to execute.

```
 var doc = $.parseXML(xml);
doc.xpath("(//NAMESET| //NAMESETFROMDATA) [HANDLE/STRINGVALUE = '" + handle+ "']");

where handle = NameSpaceAssoc::HighlightSet
```

Could anyone point me whats its doing and any pointer to improve its performance?

Consider myself a newbie in JavaScript and xml.

Comment: You question is unclear. What is meaning of `slow` and `takes ages to execute`? Add more code and create demo to show us what happen.

Comment: Add your markup to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `xpath` to select elements in javascript, should use `evaluate()` method. To better understanding See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate).

To selecting element by `evaluate()` you must to write name of tags in lowercase in select `path` because browser convert every uppercase in tag name and attribute to lowercase. To better understanding See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/sr0exfzx/).

```js
var document = "Your xml document";
var handle = "NameSpaceAssoc::HighlightSet";
var path = "(//objectset | //objectsetfromdata) [handle/stringvalue = '" + handle + "']";
var query = document.evaluate(path, doc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
```

You can compute execute time of code using this code

```js
var startDate = new Date().getTime();

// Your code

var endDate = new Date().getTime();
var executeTime = endDate - startDate;
```

I check execute time of code, it is right.

See full example in **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1eo8hvx3/)**

Comment: But the problem is evaluate is not supported by IE11

Comment: @Joe Use `xmlDoc.selectNodes(xpath)` in IE. See http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: Is there a way in terms of browser compatibility except xpath?

Comment: @Joe If you don't want to use `xpath`, you can use jquey selector like https://jsfiddle.net/t577znv2/

Comment: Thank you very much Mohammad. I got all the answers. One more thing could you please explain what is query is exactly doing?

Comment: Also can we do anything to improve the same xpath query?

Comment: @Joe What is meaning of `improve`? What do you want?

Comment: I mean for a document of bigger size it takes nearly 1.5 to execute. Also if you can put some light on the query, what its doing.

Comment: @Joe I say for your my ways and it is unlikely to exist other way to do this. Certainly if your ducument is large, time of execute increased. But if your document is on server, you can run query on server side and send result to client.

Comment: ok.. I was trying to compare the time difference for xpath and evaluate on the fiddler you shared. But when using xpath it throws uncaught TypeError: doc.xpath is not a function. Any pointer?

Comment: @Joe Javascript hasn't `xpath` method. Equivalent of `xpath` in javascript is `evaluate`.

Comment: Currently in my code I am using xpath which is giving performance issue that is why I am looking for alternative. Code is-  var jDom = $.parseXML(xml);
$(jDom).xpath(expression);

Comment: @Joe Oh, ok. You use xpath plugin. Test it.

Comment: I can notice the huge difference between xpath and evaluate on executeion. Can you help me to convert the same xpath expression to jquery selector

Comment: @Joe Yes, But you must ask new question to this work.

Comment: Thanks. I shall mark this as answered and raise a new question. Thanks again

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37320894/convert-xpath-expression-to-jquery-selector?noredirect=1#comment62161239_37320894                   New question raised. Link above.